# SMTP protocol synchronization error (input sent without waiting for greeting)

Tags: email, ssl, centos, exim

I configured exim mail server on centos. It is working with no encryption type. But not with SSL and TLS. I din't get correct solution for this type of error. Can anyone tell solution and why this error message in exim main.log file?

The error message is like below in the exim main.log file.

**2015-03-17 10:34:16 SMTP protocol synchronization error (input sent without waiting for greeting): rejected connection from H=acp-node [10.7.2.137] input="\026\003\001"**

Comment: Try by adding this line to exim.conf: 
 smtp_enforce_sync = false, then restart exim

Comment: Thank you. Tried this. I din't get this error. But still I'm not able to save email settings with SSL/TLS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the error log entry, your mail client 10.7.2.137 is trying to establish a secure (TLS) connection but your Exim server is not expecting it.

Most probably, TLS is not configured properly in your Exim configuration file. You can refer to http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-encrypted_smtp_connections_using_tlsssl.html for tutorial.

The solution is, therefore, to edit your Exim configuration file, making sure TLS certificates are defined and tls_advertise_hosts is set; and then restart Exim.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. I will try and let you know.

Comment: While saving th e Email settings in UI it shows error like 
"NOTE: SSL/TLS connections use the system certificate store. Use the link below to edit the certificate details" 
So, I changed the configuration in exim.conf file like,

Before it was

tls_certificate = /etc/pki/tls/certs/exim.pem
tls_privatekey = /etc/pki/tls/private/exim.pem

now 

tls_certificate = /opt/ssl/exim.crt
tls_privatekey = /opt/ssl/exim.crt

But still I'm not able to use SSL and TLS. How to configure this?

Answer (score 9):

> (input sent without waiting for greeting) ... input="\026\003\001"

In short: You are trying to use implicit TLS on a port where explicit TLS is needed.

In detail: There are two ways to use TLS with SMTP:

- implicit TLS, that is TLS from start. This is used on port 465 (smtps). This mode is in some SMTP stacks simply called "SSL".
- explicit TLS, that is start with plain SMTP and upgrade to TLS with the STARTTLS command. This is used on ports 25 (smtp) and 587 (submission). This mode is in some SMTP stacks simply called "TLS".

If you look around at the questions regarding use of SMTP with TLS you will find lots of confusion about how to use these modes with the various setups. And you will find lots of bad code which tries to use implicit TLS where explicit TLS is needed.

What you see is the result of the client trying to use implicit TLS on a port not suitable for this. `\026\003\001` (or hex `16 03 01`) is the start of a TLS 1.0 handshake and `input sent without waiting for greeting` refers to the fact, that the client is sending data first without waiting for the server to send the (plain text) SMTP greeting.